# error while loading shared libraries: libflann.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, centos, shared-libraries, flann

I tried compiling flann library on remote server. I compiled using root permission and want to run from an already existing account on the server. I get the following error. Can you help me figure out what is wrong. The server is centos distribution.

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libflann.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$ whereis libflann.so.1.8
libflann.so.1: /usr/lib/libflann.so.1.8 /usr/local/lib/libflann.so.1.8
```

Comment: That looks like a 32-bit library. Are you trying to execute a 64-bit executable?

Comment: I am running on a 64 bit machine. How do I find out if it is 32 bit library?

Comment: `/usr/lib` is the typical install location for 32-bit libraries. Use `file` on the executable and library to check what they are.

Comment: Oh about that, I followed some answer here that suggested to link my installation to /usr/lib and that didnt work. I dont think its 32 bit as I downloaded 64 bit one

Comment: `ldd a.out` output?

Comment: linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbfa93000)
 libflann.so.1.8 => not found
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7588515000)
 libgomp.so.1 => /lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f75882fe000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f75880e2000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7587d1f000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7588833000)

Comment: Well I copied the content of /usr/local/lib to /usr/lib64 and it worked. I wish to understand why compiling libflann source on server did not originally put it in lib64

Comment: You would have to check the makefile target for that library.